# How to make load balancing test in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, socket.io, amazon-elb

I have been trying to make load balancing test on my node js code but I didn't find any starting point from where to start.

My scenario is I wrote my server-side code in node js(full of socket emits and on) and its a multiplayer game which checks for people who are online and tries to merge them and play the game. My node code is hosted on amazon ec2 as a micro tier instance. So, how can I check what is the maximum limit my server can bear to receive the online players.

Is this something related to amazon ec2 instance? Do I need to change my ec2 instance configuration if more number of people are using my application?   (or)

Do I need to write some code in my node js to handle the increase in load? please help me out as this is something where I don't have any idea from where to start.

Comment: The AWS Elastic Load Balancer is automatic and detects a stressed server based on CPU utilization, bandwidth, hard disk reads/writes, etc. You don't have to write any code for it to work. However, since you are making a game, your individual servers probably need to be synchronized. You should tailor your question to address how to do that

Comment: Thanks @Houseman..In my case, there is only one ec2 instance(server) and I'm not running multiple servers. So, can my ec2 micro tier instance automatically able to bear the load or do I need to set up multiple ec2 instances?

Comment: It depends on how intensive your server processes are and how many people are playing your game. Watch the utilization graphs during a test. But it's useless to set up an ELB with only one server behind it.